# Postgres - format monetary value

Tags: postgresql

I am using a Postgres with Latin1 encoding. How can I format the value in a monetary form eg: `1,200.50`?

The native functions of postgres are not working in latin1, and I cannot
convert the database to utf-8. Does anyone have any idea how to format? Or
at least an idea of ​​how to change the charset directly in sql without affecting the entire database?

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables (paste the **text**, don't use images), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Comment: I need to format a value this way 1,200.59

SELECT to_char(213456.789,'"R$ " 000G000G000D99'); 

and this select does not work because the bank is latin1, and I can not in any way convince the bank to utf-8 as it will generate several problems.

Comment: This is completely independent of the encoding (unless you want to use a € currency symbol), and your statement is syntactically wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To determine how the group and decimal separators are rendered, you have to set `lc_numeric` correctly. You also have to set `lc_monetary` correctly, otherwise you may get an error that the currency symbol doesn't exist in `LATIN1` (this is surprising, but seems to be part of the `to_char` implementation).

```
SET lc_numeric = "en_US";
SET lc_monetary = "en_US";

SELECT to_char(1200.50, 'FM999G999G999D00');

 to_char  
----------
 1,200.50
(1 row)
```

This was on a Linux machine. On a different operating system, the locale names can be different.

This has nothing to do with the encoding of the database.
You must, however, use a client encoding that is compatible with the database encoding `LATIN1`. That cannot be `WIN1252`, but that's an independent problem.

Comment: did not work, the following error is displayed ERROR:  default conversion function for encoding "WIN1252" to "LATIN1" does not exist

Comment: @user9078159: you probably need to set `client_encoding` to make that error go away

Comment: I have revisited the answer, and iyou also have to set `lc_monetary`. The problem with client encoding WIN1252 is a different, independent problem.